# deserializing xml to different type

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize an XML (it's working so far). The XML reads in everything as strings.

When it goes to populate the property ID, I want to convert it to a GUID from the string. But I can't seem to get this work.

Thanks.

```
public class Feature
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string ID
        {
        set
            {
                ID = new Guid(ID);
            }
        }
```

XML:

```
<Features>
            <Feature ID="8581a8a7-cf16-4770-ac54-260265ddb0b2" FeatureName="SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features" />
</Features>
```

Comment: Your snippet has a setter calling itself, which will always result in an overflowed stack, and wouldn't compile regardless, because of a type mismatch. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesnt compile, but regardless - why don't you just change the property type from `string` to `Guid`? the conversion will happen automatically when you deserialize. Try it:

```
public class Feature
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
}
```